# Do both SOAP and/or REST refer back to WSDL?

Tags: rest, soap, wsdl

Do both SOAP and REST refer back to the WSDL? I'm having trouble distinguishing between SOAP and REST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, only SOAP does.

Essentially SOAP is a protocol with the client and server making agreements as to the kinds of data types transmitted and what actions should be taken by the server for a request. This agreement is specified in the WSDL file.

With REST, there is no agreement as the point of REST is to talk to a resource using only GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE. Nothing about the underlying implementation as specified by a WSDL file should be known to a REST client.

Comment: No problem. I am currently researching on this whole topic as well. Shoot me any questions. BTW: mind accepting and upvoting my answer?:)

Comment: I tried...it says I am not allowed to vote for this comment. Do you know why or what the workaround is?

Comment: oh, that's because you have not gained enough "reputation" points yet. make sure to keep being engaged on this site to gain those:)